# How to check array exist when using magic field

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I try to check if array exist using below code, the problem is when no image inside `getFieldOrder('image_gal')` it will return this error.

Error Output

```
Warning: array_reverse() [function.array-reverse]: The argument should be an array in /home/sritamac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/magic-fields/get-custom.php on line 306

Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/sritamac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/magic-fields/get-custom.php on line 307
```

Array Code :

```
<?php
//var
$images = getFieldOrder('image_gal');

if (is_array($images)) {

    foreach ($images as $image) {

        if (get('image_gal', 1, $image) == TRUE) { //check if image_gallery_image has image 
?> 

    <div id="wrap">
        <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <?php
            $images = getFieldOrder('image_gal');
            foreach ($images as $image) { //loop image 
            ?>
            <li>
                <a class="group3"  href="<?php echo get('image_gal', 1, $image);?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get('image_gal', 1, $image);?>" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
                </a>
            </li>  
            <?php
            }
            ?>  
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Im using this theme http://www.s5themes.com/theme/webfolio/ and wordpress version is 3.2.1.

Magic Fields plugin http://magicfields.org/

Comment: Is this correct, that you are overwriting your image variable inside the foreach loop? If so, change is_array($images) to !empty($images)

Comment: the error still same.. my problem same with this guy https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/magic-fields/Sw4KxMAvQ_A  still no solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because, in `array_reverse()` and `sort()` you are passing a variable which is non-array.

Solution :

1. Check your parameter, before executing these function, execute these
   functions only if the parameter is array. You can use `is_array`
   function.

   ```
   if(is_array($array)){
       sort($array);
   }
   ```
2. Check your parameter, if it is null or non-array make it array. before passing it to function.

   ```
   if(!is_array($array) || $array = "" || $array = NULL){
       $array = array();
   }
   sort($array);
   ```

I recommend you the second solution, because even if the array is null it will not affect the other functionality.